# Mercurial: Easiest way to revert to old version of file when everything is committed?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Let's say I have a repo with 5 changesets committed, for simplicity. I modified file A in changesets 2 and 4. I am a sloppy programmer however, and the changes I made in 4 are wrong. I would like the file to be reverted to exactly how it was in changeset 2. The rest of the changesets address other files that I do not want to revert.

What is the best way to do this? I only know dumb/un-clever ways :(

```
    changeset: 1
    user: jdf
    date:
    summary: first change, other file

    changeset: 2
    user: jdf
    date:
    summary: file A change - this is the file I want in this state

    changeset: 3
    user: jdf
    date:
    summary: change, other file

    changeset: 4
    user: jdf
    date:
    summary: file A change - this was dumb and I don't want it

    changeset: 5
    user: jdf
    date:
    summary: change, other file
```

So in hypothetical changeset 6, I would have file A in the same state as it was after changeset 2, but without having lost the work from changesets 3 and 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on whether everything you did in changeset 4 was dumb or whether you only want to restore this one file as found in changeset 2.

If everything in changeset 4 is a bad idea, undo the whole changeset:

```
hg backout -r4
```

If you only need to revert the state of the single FILE to that of changeset 2, then use

```
hg revert -r2 FILE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `hg backout -r <changeset>`.

Documentation of [backout](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Backout):

> Backout works by applying a changeset that's the opposite of the changeset to be backed out. That new changeset is committed to the repository, and eventually merged

Comment: In this exact example where changeset 4 only makes changes you don't want anymore backout is perfect.  If, however, you want to backout multiple commits worth of changes to a single file or backout a changeset but only the changes to some files it might just be easier to do `hg cat -r 2 fileA > fileA` and then commit it.

Comment: @Ry4an: "backout a changeset but only the changes to some files" can be also `hg revert -r $REV FILE` under some conditions